# What is the expected cost of getting the engineering degree with the following details?

Tags: probability, statistics, finance, economics

What is the expected total cost of getting the engineering degree until he is actually getting one with the following details when the risk is taking account to the expected total cost?

Notes: ABC college's engineering overall graduation rate is 50 percentage, that is everyone had uniform chance of graduating and the total cost for the student who are able to graduate is 200000 dollars in case he/she is getting it in one times, the average cost for the student who are not able to graduate is 80000 dollars, so the student who are able to getting in the second time will have the cost of 280000 dollars and so on.

My work is that the answer will be (1/2) (200000 + 80000 x 0) + 1/4(200000 +80000 x 1) + 1/8(200000 + 80000 x 2)+... is that correct?

This question sounds too simple with a feeling that just a few step could address this, maybe I am too stupid or this problem is too tricky that I couldn't figure it out on my own.

Edit 1: "...the average amount that students spend for each degree earned is greater than 200,000." as mentioned by David K.

Edit 2: The fact is that it is just in this problem that everyone had uniform chance of graduating, that is 50%

Comment: Well, what simple thing did you think addressed this?

Comment: How do you compute expectation?

Comment: But 200000 x 1/2 + 80000 x 1/2 doesn't make any sense... @TedShifrin

Comment: The expected cost of _attempting_ this course of study is somewhere between 80,000 and 200,000. But the cost to each student who actually _gets the degree_ is 200,000, no more and no less, while the average amount that students spend for each degree earned is greater than 200,000. One thing we can be fairly sure of is that this is not the best-worded question we've seen today.

Comment: @lulu But 200000 x 1/2 + 80000 x 1/2 doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @DavidK what is missing?

Comment: The first sentence of your "Notes" is what's relevant. There is a 50% chance of completing the degree and a 50% chance of not completing it. Why do you say the correct answer makes no sense? You're taking the arithmetic mean of the two costs, and that makes perfect sense if half the people finish and half the people don't. DavidK is complaining that it's not an entirely realistic representation of the world; gee, what a surprise in a math problem.

Comment: @DavidK Also, I believe that the expected cost of attempting this course of study is somewhere between 0 and 200,000 instead of 80000.

Comment: What's missing is a clear understanding of what the question asked. I don't know what is meant by "the risk is account to the cost." If I were buying melons one at a time for $\$2$ each and half turn out to be rotten inside, then I can expect to pay $\$4$ for each edible melon that I buy. But one does not purchase engineering degrees that way.

Comment: I think you already found the expected cost of attempting the course and it is clearly greater than $80000.$

Comment: @TedShifrin Assuming there is no cost to the students who didn't graduated, there is still at least expected cost of 400000 dollars = 200000/(1/2) dollars for these who graduated, Isn't it?

Comment: @DavidK It is just in this problem that everyone had uniform chance of graduating, that is 50%.

Comment: The value $\frac 12 \times (200000+80000)$ makes perfect sense.  That is how much a random student will pay.

Comment: Try some examples. Suppose 100 students enroll this year, 50 graduate and 50 wash out. How much did they spend altogether? How much is that when you average it over the students who graduated? What if you average over all 100 students? You know the cost to the failed students is _not_ generally zero; the problem statement says it averages 80000. On the other hand, 400000 times the number of graduates will be a lot more money than the students spent altogether, so that's not a good average.

Comment: @Victor: I have no idea why you are *dividing* by $1/2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin The issue is not so much that the problem is unrealistic; it is that it is unclear what the question _is._ There are several averages in play here, and the word "risk" is apparently supposed to tell us which one we want, but I don't know which one that is. That is, the question as stated is a _finance_ problem and needs some work to convert it to a _math_ problem. My _guess_ is that the desired average is total student costs divided by number of degrees received, but that's only a guess.

Comment: I read only "what is the expected cost of getting an engineering degree?" ... The end of the sentence makes absolutely no sense to me, I agree. It's not even English.

Comment: @TedShifrin OP just edited the question to imply that each student keeps reapplying (and keeps getting readmitted) to the school until they finally make it through, and they have an (independently distributed?) 50% chance each time (apparently this school gives out degrees by roulette wheel rather than according to ability).

Comment: Oh, so this is now a Markov process? Who knows.

Comment: Now the cost should be $120000 + 80000X$ where $X$ is the number of enrollment needed for that student to get the degree. Then $X$ just follows a Geometric distribution and the should be done. We assumed the student will keep repeat enrolling if he has not get the degree yet and each time is independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems correct.

Assuming they can keep enrolling until the end of time, then they will always pay $$80,000n+200,000$$

dollars where $n$ is the amount of times they had to enroll prior to the enrollment in which they actually graduated. Assuming independence and each time they enroll, they will graduate with a $0.5$ probability, we just get an infinite sum

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(80,000n+200,000)\cdot {0.5^{n+1}}$$

Wolfram alpha says that this converges (fortunately) and gives $280,000$.